# C++ - Definition of A Member of A Class Template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `listmap` with a member called `iterator`.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less = xless<Key>>
class listmap {
public:
   class iterator;
   //...
}
```

The definition for iterator is out of list map as follows,

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less = xless<Key>>
class listmap<Key, Value, Less>::iterator {
//...
}
```

`less` is a template class for comparison,

```
template <typename Type>
struct xless {
   bool operator() (const Type& left, const Type& right) const {
      return left < right;
   }
};
```

I'm just running a simple test to see whether it works, but it gives me this error

`cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template`

My understanding of template is very low. Why can't I use `xless` in definition of `iterator` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class declaration for `listmap` you provide a default for the last template type (i.e., `class Less = xless<Key>`).

In your definition of the `iterator` you specify the default again, remove it.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less>
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
class listmap<Key, Value, Less>::iterator
{
    //...
}
```